# PHPunit Mocking not returning specified value

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-testing

I have a my controller class like below

```
Class UserController {
  public function getName(){
    return "test_name"
  }

  public function hello(){
    return getName()."!"
  }
}
```

An accompanying unit test as seen below

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\User\UserController;

class UserTest extends TestCase{
  public function testExample(){
   $mockGetName = $this->getMockBuilder(UserController::class)->onlyMethods(['getName'])->getMock();
   $mockGetName->method('getName')->willReturn("dummy");

   $userController = new $mockGetName();
   dump($userController->getName("test name"));
   }
}
```

When mocked getName() returns `null` instead of "dummy". Anyone have any idea why the specified return value is not being returned?

Comment: Do not do a `unit test` on a controller, that is a `feature test`. Also, you should use `Mockery` instead of `$this->getMockBuilder()`. I have no idea what that will return but `Mockery` is widely used, so everyone will know it more.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Mockery shout. With regards to the former, I'm mocking out a simple helper function in a controller

Comment: Still, you do not test controllers as unit tests ! If you need a helper function and it is in a controller, that is a "mini" alarm that something is not designed correctly, as the controller should do whatever it needs in a run (few lines of code) or use a service/helper (a file/class in other places, but not the controller).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I used `createPartialMock` instead of the `mockBuilder` and it returns what is needed.

```
$mockGetName = $this->createPartialMock(UserController::class, ['getName']);
$mockGetName->method('getName')->willReturn("test name");
```